# Django project with fcgi

Tags: django

I am trying to deploy a second Django project on a dedicated server using fcgi. However if I run `python manage.py runfcgi`in my project I get the following output:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en-us
```

followed by the correct html output.

My .htaccess is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ /home/username/public_html/my_project/media/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin_media/(.*)$ /home/username/public_html/my_project/admin_media/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(django\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cgi-bin/django.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

And my django.fcgi is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.6
import sys
import os

# insert PYTHONPATH values here, including the path to your application
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/darwinfo/lib/python/')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/darwinfo/django-projects/my_project/')

# location of your application's settings file.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method = "threaded", daemonize = "false", maxchildren=3, minspare=0, maxspa
re=1)
```

And when I navigate to the url I get a 500 error. I don't believe this a Django error as my admin mail is configured correctly and I get no notifications.

Any suggestions what I can do to remedy this situation

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a flup installed as suggested by: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/?from=olddocs ?

You have to have flup installed in virt_env for your new project.